# What is a proper way to POST multiple sets of data through AJAX to .Net Core EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have seen numerous examples, mostly wrong or outdated concepts written a decade ago. I cant seem to find a way to submit multiple variables to the ef core database using Ajax. I can get it to work with one, but cant seem to get it to work with multiple. Not sure if I am doing something wrong? I just get a syntax error on the **var dataObjects**

Ajax Call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("#cosubmitbutton").click(function () {
                if ($('#CompanyId').val() == "-1" || $('#CompanyId').val() == "0") {
                    toastr.warning("Please select company / Client!");
                    return false;
                }


                var dataObjects = { 
                CompanyId = $("#CompanyId").val();
                TechnicalContact = $("#TechnicalContactId").val();
                TCEmailAddress = $("#TCEmailAddressId").val();
                NumOfWorkstations = $("#NumOfWorkstationsId").val();
                NumOfUsers = $("#NumOfUsersId").val();
                NumOfServers = $("#NumOfServersId").val();
                NumOfFirewalls = $("#NumOfFirewallsId").val();
                NumOfSwitches = $("#NumOfSwitchesId").val();
                NumOfAps = $("#NumOfApsId").val();
                Domain = $("#DomainId").val();
               };


                //ObjThreadItem = JSON.stringify({ 'ObjThread': ThreadItem});

                console.log("Json Stringify CommonPostData: ", JSON.stringify(dataObjects))
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    url: '/Onboarding/Client/CreateClientOverview',
                    type: "post",
                    data: JSON.stringify(dataObjects),
                    success: function (result) {
                        debugger
                        toastr.success("Information successfully updated on server!");
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            });

    </script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public JsonResult CreateClientOverview(ClientOverview Modal)
{   
                _context.ClientOverview.Add(Modal);
               _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(Modal);

}
```

Comment: its because you have = in dataObjects but objects in javascript have semicolon : instead of this !!! And also don't end with ; but with ,

Comment: Thanks! That def fixed it. Too many wrong tutorials on the internet over the Ajax portion with the = and the ; being in the code.... Now onto figure out why I get a 405  method not allowed on this :-D Likely my button bc it looks for a view instead of an action on a controller